# Jsoup Selector "not"

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, wiki, jsoup

This code here:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Francisco").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("h2:contains(Get around) ~ *:not(h2:contains(See) ~ *)"));
```

outputs http://pastebin.com/gkcCfr1F. Is there a selector to make the "not" selector inclusive? Right now it is removing everything after the "see", when I'd like to remove the last h2 tag with the id="see" along with the everything else because I'm attempting to parse individual sections of a wiki.

The final output that I would like to obtain is: http://pastebin.com/ntpVrgui

Comment: can you add sample output manually(c/p html which you want to obtain) it's a bit hard to understand without output example (for me)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

Get the content div :

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean start = false;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Francisco").get();
            Elements content = doc.select("#content");
            for (Element element : content) {
                /*Pseudo code
                   if element is h3 and it contains span with id Navigating and if start is  
false append it to stringbuilder, set start to true, else append everything in between until you reach h2 with span id See
                  */                
    }
```

Comment: if(element.tagName().equals("h3"))
I can't even get the condition "if element is h3" working. Any ideas? Also, I've noticed that content.size() returns 1, so that means there's only one element...

Comment: using doc.select("#content") returns only one element, so I switched to doc.getAllElements(). I was able to get the first condition with  if(element.tagName().equals("h3")) but I have no idea about the span with id "navigating". I've been reading the api for hours.

Comment: I've got it working http://pastebin.com/GQyDyxPT... But now one bug remains 
At the end, there's some garbage html that looks like this that appears at the bottom of the html generated http://pastebin.com/jwNAz4R9

Comment: what exactly you mean by "garbage" html? this http://pastebin.com/jwNAz4R9 ? you want get rid of this?

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of it. It's not present on the actual site so I'm not sure why that html is even there.